# Connect VPN inside VPN

Tags: macos, network, wifi, security, vpn

I am using my college Wi-Fi connection which seems to use a VPN network. I was trying to connect to another openVPN connection that is provided by my company. But I was not able to connect to the openVPN, it seemed that I was trying to use VPN inside a VPN.

After some web searching I found that this can be resolved using virtual machines, but I don’t want to use it since I need to download and upload huge chunks of data from cloud that might not be possible using VMs.

There is another way too, something like double VPN chaining. I was trying to do this using tunnelblick but was not able to do it.

I am clueless how can I resolve this issue. Any help is highly appreciated.

Some more details:

1. I don’t have any vpn configuration file or ca.cert from my institute. They provided us with the Id and password which was used on there portal to connect to institute network.
2. I have the configuration file for VPN from my company.
3. Operating system: macOS Monterey
4. Laptop: MacBook Air M1
5. I used tunnelblick to connect to VPN.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think your college WiFi is using a "VPN network"? Can you reach normal internet hosts from your WiFi? Have you tested the OpenVPN connection from a different network? I really don't understand how you come to the conclusion you have a VPN-in-VPN scenario here, it would only matter if you were trying to establish two VPN connections from the same Mac. There's so much involved here, and so many details missing, probably your best option is to contact your company VPN admin and ask them for help.

Comment: I tried connecting to openVPN by using mobile data, which works fine. So I concluded that it’s VPN in VPN. Can you please specify what do you mean by normal internet hosts?

Comment: Also, we are restricted to use some sites when using institute Wi-Fi, so I think it uses VPN

Comment: This very much sounds like a _firewall_ issue in your institute, not VPN. You need to contact your institute's network admin or consult any help pages they might have. It's possible they only allow HTTP or HTTPS traffic, maybe even over a proxy.